# FiPy - Domain stretches / Frame growth

Tags: python, fipy

I'm trying to solve a simple diffusion equation (dT/dt = K d2T/dx2  ) on a domain whose depth ( h(t) ) changes in time. The resulting equation is therefore:

```
dT/dt = K/h^2 d2T/dx2 + z/h dh/dt dT/dz
```

where z is now a fixed 0->1 domain.

The new term is frame advection and I'm trying to include it as such but I'm struggling with the spatially dependent coefficient.

When I include it outside the convection term:

```
mesh.cellCenters[0]*PowerLawConvectionTerm(...)
```

I get this error:

```
TermMultiplyError: Must multiply terms by int or float
```

But if I reorganise the equation so the spatial dependence is inside the convection term:

```
PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff=(mesh.cellCenters[0]**2,),...)
```

I get a different error when solving the equation:

```
AssertionError: assert( len(id1) == len(id2) == len(vector) )
```

What is the correct way to include these terms? Is there a silly mistake I'm making somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this might be to split the last term into two parts so that the equation in FiPy is written

```
fipy.TransientTerm() == fipy.DiffusionTerm(K / h**2) \
                        + fipy.ConvectionTerm(z * z_hat * h_t / h) \
                        - h_t / h * T
```

In FiPy there can't be multipliers outside of the term's derivative so an extra source term is required. Here it is assumed that

```
K = 1. ## some constant
h = fipy.Variable(...) ## variable that is continuously updated
h_old = fipy.Variable(...) ## variable that is continuously updated
h_t = (h - h_old) / dt ## variable dependent on h and h_old
T = fipy.CellVariable(...)
z_hat = [0, 1] ## vector required for convection term coefficient
```

`T` is the variable being solved for, `h` and `h_old` are explicilty updated at every sweep or time step using `setValue` based on some formula. Additionally, the last term can be split into an explicit and an implicit source

```
- h_t / h * T -> - fipy.ImplicitSourceTerm(1 / dt) + h_old / h / dt * T
```

depending on how the `h_t` is evaluated. The implicit source should make the solution very stable.

Comment: How are you defining your z? I'm using `mesh.cellCenters[0]` (I'm working in 1D for now but it will become the vertical dimension) and I get the AssertError above.
I've found a workaround here [http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/diffusion-with-space-dependent-drift-in-fipy] where your combination `z*z_hat` becomes `CellVariable(mesh=mesh,value=z)` - Is there a better way?

h_t is calculated from the fields themselves `h_t = A*f(T)` at z=h and then used in a simple update `h_new = h_old + dt*h_t` I guess your suggestion of splitting the source terms wouldn't work here?
Thanks!